# How to insert new rows by certain group in Google Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am stuck with a question about how to insert new rows among my dataset. As the attached picture shows, I have a dataset with hundreds of millions rows and there are two columns represent the valid_from and valid_to time date.

I want to duplicate the latest row, which is where the valid_to is 9999-12-31 and change the valid_from to current date, since I want to make a line graph with the current_date as the latest data point.

So, all in all, what I want is duplicating the latest row in each pricelist_id and product_id, and change the valid_from to current_date, and the valid_to should be 9999-12-31 as well.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnca9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjXbu.png)